# Desktop icons refresh when add a new Favourite to Internet Explorer 9

Tags: windows-explorer

Vista home premium edition (32)
Desktop HP Pavilion, 2 CPU, 4GB memory

After adding a new favorite, especially if it has a favicon, all desktop icons refresh. As you might know, it is not a tragedy, because all works well. But this process takes about a 30 seconds or more and a lot of CPU !!!!

What has been done:
1. Icon cash rebuild
2. Page file increased
3. "Max Cached Icons" in Registry increased a couple of times to be now 4096

There is a lot of garbage on Web regarding this, but nothing pointing on this specific problem
Thanks in advance,

Valery

Comment: Why do you use IE and on Vista to boot? Get rid of both as fast as possible. Or downgrade to IE8, it has no such issues.

Comment: Kard, thanks for an answer. Did not understand what you wrote about boot? I suppose you suppose me to get rid of Vista and IE? May be of Microsoft at all? Good idea, but not now. I would not want to downgrade to IE8. I know how to, but with Microsoft it is not easy. In other words, you have no answrer. Will wait for somebody else.

Comment: No, I don't have an answer, that's why I only posted a comment. I have had such horrible experiences with Vista, I always advise people to get rid of it. And IE only started being a normal browser after v10, in my opinion. (To boot = in adition to.)